# How to create custom pages (Drupal 6.x)

Tags: drupal, themes, drupal-themes

In the **template.php** file I inserted the code below:
I found a tutorial online that gives the code, but I'm confused on how to get it to work.

I copied the code below and inserted it into the **template.php** from the theme **HTML5_base**.
I duplicated the **page.tpl.php** file and created custom pages -- ***page-gallery.tpl.php*** and ***page-articles.tpl.php***. I inserted some text to the files just see that I've navigated to the pages w/ the changes. It looks like Drupal is not recognizing gallery.tpl.php and page-articles.tpl.php.

**In the template.php there are the following functions:**

html5_base_preprocess_page()

html5_base_preprocess_node()

html5_base_preprocess_block()

**In the tutorial it uses these functions**:

phptemplate_preprocess_page()

phptemplate_preprocess_block()

phptemplate_preprocess_node()

```
 function phptemplate_preprocess_page(&$vars)

{
    //code block from the Drupal handbook

    //the path module is required and must be activated
    if(module_exists('path'))
    {
        //gets the "clean" URL of the current page
        $alias = drupal_get_path_alias($_GET['q']);

        $suggestions = array();
        $template_filename = 'page';
        foreach(explode('/', $alias) as $path_part)
        {
            $template_filename = $template_filename.'-'.$path_part;
            $suggestions[] = $template_filename;
        }

        $vars['template_files'] = $suggestions;
    }
}

function phptemplate_preprocess_node(&$vars)
{
    //default template suggestions for all nodes
    $vars['template_files'] = array();
    $vars['template_files'][] = 'node';

    //individual node being displayed
    if($vars['page'])
    {    
        $vars['template_files'][] = 'node-page';
        $vars['template_files'][] = 'node-'.$vars['node']->type.'-page';
        $vars['template_files'][] = 'node-'.$vars['node']->nid.'-page';
    }
    //multiple nodes being displayed on one page in either teaser
    //or full view
    else
    {
        //template suggestions for nodes in general
        $vars['template_files'][] = 'node-'.$vars['node']->type;
        $vars['template_files'][] = 'node-'.$vars['node']->nid;

        //template suggestions for nodes in teaser view
        //more granular control
        if($vars['teaser'])
        {
            $vars['template_files'][] = 'node-'.$vars['node']->type.'-teaser';    
            $vars['template_files'][] = 'node-'.$vars['node']->nid.'-teaser';
        }
    }
}

function phptemplate_preprocess_block(&$vars)
{
    //the "cleaned-up" block title to be used for suggestion file name
    $subject = str_replace(" ", "-", strtolower($vars['block']->subject));

    $vars['template_files'] = array('block', 'block-'.$vars['block']->delta, 'block-'.$subject);    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah! That's a lot of pain to do this.

Why don't you try the [Ctools](http://drupal.org/project/ctools) and [Panels](http://drupal.org/project/panels) modules.

**Ctools** has a lot of useful modules, the one you'd make good use of is called "**Page Manager**". It will allow you to create custom pages of your choice, and apply custom layouts using the **Panels** module.

Hope this simplifys things.

Comment: i'm running to the problem where the pages i'm creating from "Page Manager" is not showing up in my primary links

Comment: You'll have to manually add the pages, from Administer > Site building > Menus (admin/build/menu) and enter the path you specified in Page Manager when you created the pages. Drupal does not automatically add Menus, you'll have to do that manually.